# Potential bias in a study design

Tags: inference, bias, causality, case-control-study

I am trying to design a study regarding Diabetes. I have patients with test results of some indicator about their situation - sugar levels, but not in the classic sense that you may know.

Every patient has slightly different behavior in this regard so I calculated a score which ranges from 0 to 1 that basically captures the "unbalanceness" of the patient, 0 being super balanced and 1 being super unbalanced.

In the study I want to have 2 groups: both started from more or less the same levels of test values - but one becomes unbalanced later on (sort of "treatment" group) and the other stays balanced through the whole period (sort of a "control" group).

I decide on the assignment of each patient to one of the groups based on the score that I've calculated. The problem is that when looking at the distribution of the score values I have reached these conclusions:

1. When Score = 0 it is safe to assign the patient to the "Balanced" group.
2. When Score > 0.2 it is safe to assign the patient to the "Unbalanced" group.
3. The area of 0 < Score <= 0.2 is inconclusive.

My question is - am I in risk to suffer from some sort of selection bias here if I am to remove the last group from my study?
The reason I want to do this is because I want to provide the model the best starting point to inference from. Any suggestions?

My goal in this study is to see which variables are affecting the patient's
likelihood to become "unbalanced".

Comment: Why are you trying to discretize a continuous variable? Why not just model the 'Score' values directly?

Comment: @mkt: My dependent variable eventually will be a binary one that says 1 - unbalanced; 0 - balanced. The reason I do that is that I need some sort of comparison group when I analyze the effect of each variable on the probability of being unbalanced.

Comment: I think you should include more information about your goals in the question - at present, we don't have enough information to provide you with the best advice on how to model this. But removing your category #3 is not a good idea.

Comment: `My goal in this study is to see which variables are affecting the patient's likelihood to become "unbalanced".` Do you want to see which variables causally affects the "unbalancedness" or the variables that best predict "unbalancedness"?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli: The former. I want to see which variables causally affects the "unbalancedness".

Comment: And your main worry is ignoring the third group, the "inconclusive" one?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli: Yes, this is one of my main worries because if I just discard it I am risking running into a potential selection bias, right?